# Jquery object within an object issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dictionary

I have this object:

```
question =  {
  "name":"Foo",
  "number":"123", 
  "options":{"1":"1 - 20","2":"21 - 30","etc":"etc"} 
}
```

now if i do :

```
$(question.options).each(function(k,v){
    console.log(k,v)
    // This should spit out: 1,a; 2,b; etc,etc ....
});
```

But its spits out options as a single object : 0 Object { 1="1 - 20", 2="21 - 30", more...}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$.each(object, fn)` to iterate over a plain JS object.  jQuery doesn't officially support passing a plain object to its constructor.

```
$.each(question.options, function( key, value ){
    console.log( key, value );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the generic iterator function

`$.each(question.options, function(k,v) {console.log(k,v);});`